# How to update previous Items in Android Recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewmodel, android-adapterview

I have a RecyclerView to list a set of data. And on clicking each item , I have validation to check previous item is entered or not. If that item is not entered I want to enable an inline error (which is hidden in normal case) message in the previous row. I have done the scenario as shown below but error is showing only in the current row. Anyone suggest how I can enable/update  previous row or a specific row.

```
public  boolean _validateListItems(int itemIndex)
    {
        int previousItemIndex = itemIndex - 1;


        for (int i = 0; i <= previousItemIndex; i++)
        {

            if ((listRecyclerItem.get(i).getEnable()==0))
            {

              return false;
            }
        }
return true;
    }


    holder.expand_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position>0){
                if(_validateListItems(position))
                {
                    
                    mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
                    notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition);
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
                else
                 {

                    

                        holder.error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.error.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.error_red));
                    

                } 


                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all *RecyclerView* is something that recycle view. `View` is generated is based on *Data Model*.

So, lets store the user `button/checkbox` click/checked action) to the respective `Model/Item`. To run the validation, get the items from the `Adapter` and check your conditions in `Activity/Fragment` [Looping is an expensive operation, use `Coroutine` or `RxJava`]. Execute your validation and if `Validation` is true for an item, just update the `Item` from the list and finally update the `Adapter`. You can pass the *Error* message in the item and render it to the `View`. And finally, must use *DiffUtil* to update the items in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an interface for your adapter that has callback to your viewModel and when each item changed you can return the call back ito viewmodel and store it in an object or array
for example :

```
interface Callback { void onDataChanged(int itemPosition); }
```

call that method in onBindViewHolder when your item text changed

and in view model add the returned item into a list
when you clicked on a button, you can check the items if your necessary item didn't exist you can return error